# Tilemap with enormous tileset data for OpenGL rendering (texture as an image is not an option)

Tags: opengl, tile

I have big binary file. It contains 32x32 pixels tiles. Each pixel is 32 bits RBG color. Because of the binary file structure, it cannot be rendered to the texture image.

Last time I've tried to load generated texture with SFML with next dimensions 40 416 x 512 pixels produces exception that such textures are not supported.

How can I render tiles on screen without texture and uv coords manipulation?

Because in each tutorial related to tilemaps I see uv texture coords manipulation only. I need some other way to render map with tiles from file.

Binary file has next sections:
Array of megatile groups.
Array of megatiles.
Array of minitiles.
Color palette.

Each megatile group is array with 16 megatile indecies.
Each megatile is 8x8 array with minitile indecies.
Each minitile is 4x4 array of color indecies from palette.
Palette is array of 256 32bits RGB colors.

For example:

```
First megatile group just contains 16 0:
[0, 0, ..., 0] (0 x 16)
0-indexed megatile is array with minitile indexes size of 8x8. All its elementes are 0.
[0, 0, ..., 0] (0 x 64)
0-indexed minitile is an 4x4 array. Each element represent color from palette. All its elements are 0.
[0, 0, ... 0] (0 x 16)
0-indexed color from pallete is just black color in 32 bits rgb.
```

Tilemap cell is defined by megatile group index and megatile index in a group. 
So at any point for some tile (defined by pair of megatile group and megatile from this group) from tilemap I can get array of 32x32 pixels. 
How can I render tilemap?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179341/discussion-on-question-by-denis-detochka-tilemap-with-enormous-tileset-data-for).

Answer (score 0):

How do I draw a many GB image by OpenGL, when there's not enough GPU memory?

First idea: By chunks.

If you are going to draw a fixed image, no camera change, no zoom change, then the method may be: Fill a texture with every chunk, draw it, repeat with another chunk. The GPU will discard out-of-field parts, or overlap different parts of the image in the same pixel. For not fixed view, this is impractical, horribly slow.

But, wait, all GB really?

A 4K 3840x2160 = 8.3 MPixels monitor needs 8.3 x 4 = 33.2 MB of RGBA data.

The question is how to select 33.2 MB among so many GB of raw data.

Let's say you have an array of tiles (each tile is a chunck of the big image).

The first improvement is not sending to the GPU the tiles which will fall out of the field of view. This can be tested using in the CPU side the typical MVP matrix with the four corners of the tile.

The second improvement is when a tile is too far from the camera but inside the perspective/orthogonal-projection fustrum. It will be seen as a single pixel. Why send to the GPU the whole tile, when a point for that pixel is enough?

Both improvements can be achieved with a [quadtree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree) better than an array.

It stores pointers or identifyiers to the tiles. But also for intermediate *nodes* a *representative point* with the average color of its sub-nodes. Or a representative tile that "compresses" several tiles.

Traverse the qtree. Discard nodes (and thus their branches) out of the fustrum. Render representative points/tiles instead of textures when the tile is too far. Render the whole tile when some edge is more that 1 pixel size.

You won't send just 33.2 MB, but something below 100 MB, which is fairly easy to deal with.

Comment: Ok, maybe I do not understand something. 
I'll try to explain again. I have a square 32x32 pixels on screen and 32x32 pixel array. Is there a way to colorize square with colors array without creating a texture?

Comment: @DenisDetochka Yes. Use a `glDrawXXX` call for each square (as a first idea, there are more advanced techniques). In the fragment shader ouput the color you wish, passed as a uniform or read from some sort of buffer.

Comment: So, I can use some fragment shader to colorize 100 32x32 tiles with unique 32x32 color arrays on screen without creating a texture just by passing some buffer with colors? If so, could you please put it as another answer, I will accept it.

Comment: @DenisDetochka If each tile has a unique color, pass this color as an *uniform*. If not, the easiest way is use a texture, other buffers will overcomplicate the solution.

Comment: Thanks. That is what I was looking for. Please put this comment as another answer, so I will be able to accept that.

Comment: BTW you've said that **their are more advanced techniques** instead of rendereing every square. Could you please clarify? 
If I create tilemap mesh, do I still need to pass to fragment shader each color arrays, that are used with tiles? So, on tilemap has 512x1024 tiles, mostly all of them uses unique 32x32 color array, for example 400x1024. Do I still need to pass 400x1024x32x32 pixels to fragment shader? If so, can it be optimised somehow?

Comment: @DenisDetochka The point is how much data will you store in the GPU to avoid sending it again and again or to avoid zillions of `glDrawXXX` calls. Data can be stored in typical VBOs (for vertices positions), in textures (typically for colors, one color for each texture uv coordinates) or more sophisticated [SSBOs](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Shader_Storage_Buffer_Object). One way to avoid many `glDrawXXX` calls is [Indirect rendering](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Rendering#Indirect_rendering). All of it is far more complicated than send chunks and use textures.

Comment: thanks a lot for your response, I'll take a look. How I can make you comment an asnwer?

Comment: How am I answering you? About tile rendering? About avoiding textures? About using chunks? Other?

Comment: About avoiding textures. If I understood correctly, you've specified several techniques, which can be used instead of using texture.

Comment: @DenisDetochka I can edit my answer. Anyhow, I would like to know why you want to avoid textures. If you don't feel comfortable with them you'll feel worst with SSBOs.

Comment: Ok, so how I see this. To render some random tilemap I would need to use any tile from binary file. The way which is recomemnded by tutorials: we have tilemap mesh with 100x100 tiles for example. Each tile is represented by some u v coordinates. But in my case if I use one texture for one tilemap mesh, this texture will be more that 6 GB.
In tutorials texture is represented by some image, which has several tiles, basically less than 5. I've got tiles from starcraft. And their count is much bigger than 5. If I render all tiles one by one in some image file used to create texture - I will fail.

Comment: @DenisDetochka Each tile is represented by some indices to the big image (say, it starts at 4th subtile of 2nd megatile). Once you have the queried tile, extracted from the big image, you can render it by a simple texture of the same size of the extracted tile. If all pixels of this tile are the same color is when you can avoid texture. But having two routes (with and without textures) is more complicated than a single texture way.

Comment: Updated question, maybe it will make it more clear.
What about pixel shader? 
I have a tilemap mesh with 100x100 square polygons.
May I pass encoded binary file (which is about 2 MB on hardware disk), pass tilemap as a matrix , each cell of which contains megatile group index and megatile index, and decode colors on the fly?

Comment: Ripi2, my mistake... I've run tests again. The problem is not in the size of texture... it is actually 64 MB :( sorry for confusion. Texture becomes to high to be loaded. I've checked again, I have 1263 megatile groups, each group is 32 pixel in height and 32x16 pixels in width, if I want to save its structure like in binary file. so dimensions of texture are 40 416 x 512 pixels. And last try to load such texture with SMFL leaded to exception.